# design pattern for different processing methods that share some common processing chains

Tags: java, c++, design-patterns

I have a question related to design pattern. Suppose now I want to analyze the input data in different ways. I guess that a pretty idea should be that different methods can be regarded as different classes. As those methods share something in common when it comes to the processing chain. For example, each method will read the data from the media first, and then do some kind of normalization. After the analysis is finished, the result should be written to a file. Therefore, when I design the class for different process method, I firstly design a base class for all the methods:

```
class Base
{
 private:
   void read_data();
   void normalize_data();
   virtual void write_data()=0;
   virtual void process_data()=0;
 public:

   bool run_the_method()
  {
    read_data();
    normalize_data();
    process_data();
    write_data();

   }

}
```

For the method class, what I should do is to redefine the virtual function `process_data` and `write_data`. Now my only concern is the output of the analysis after performing each method. Although the input of the method is the same regardless of the method, the output of the method may be different. For some methods, their output are images; for some methods, their output are vectors, which can be stored in a text file. This will affect the arguments in the function `process_data()` as well as the `write_data()` function.  What I can think of is to derive several classes based on the `Base` class.

```
  class OutputImage:public Base
    {

     pulbic:
        OutputImage():Base();
        virtual void write_data() { // writing images to file};
        virtual void process_data() = 0;
    }

   class OutputText:public Base
    {

     pulbic:
        OutputImage():Base();
        virtual void write_data() { // writing text to file};
        virtual void process_data() = 0;
    }
```

The basic idea is that depending on the output format of the processing method, all the methods can be further derived from `OutputImage` class or `OutputText` class. For example:

```
class ProcessMethod:public  OutputText
{
  public:
    virtual void process_data()
    {
     }
}
```

Now my question is: is it a right class design strategy? are there smart ways of defining different processing method in a hierarchy class structure? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider creating separate interfaces Reader, Normalizer, Processor and Writer. Especially for testability, this would allow you to mock the reading and writing (suppose you create some data in memory instead for the unit test). The create a director or workflow class that takes these separate components and uses them together.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put your output implementation details into inheritance since it is already used for separating different algorithms of analysing input data, if I understood you correctly. Instead you should move(encapsulate) output implementation logic into another class hierarchy. Otherwise you may end up creating many subclasses that differ only by output implementation, but have the same algorithm of analysis. With implementation class hierarchy you may combine different implementations with different algorithms.

In short, [Bridge pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) is exactly what you are looking for.